# Add # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- will stop loading css and js file?

Tags: python, django, utf-8, external

I put the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the begining of my `view.py` to solve the chinese charater encoding problem, but after adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` the webpage won't load the css and js file.  Remove `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and the page will load fine!

Here is code:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/login.css">
```

I also add `DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'` in settings.

WTF?

Well, I try to comment out the following from the settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

The page loads fine, but in order to use Django message framework I have to use the above code.

Comment: Are you setting an encoding properly in your HTML document?

Comment: yes i did check out the update

Comment: @chenlieng You should be declaring it as soon as possible, before any resources are loaded. If you move the `meta` tag to the beginning of your `head`, does it change anything?

Comment: What do you have set for USE_I18N? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: not working after set USE_I18N = False

Answer (score 0):

Set USE_I18N = True

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)
```